# Перевод "wholesome exercise of the Amorous disposition"

Tags: перевод

Помогите, пожалуйста, перевести выражение "wholesome exercise of the Amorous disposition" в следующем отрывке из философской статьи:

> The truth is that there is a real plane for the wholesome exercise of the Amorous disposition that is part and parcel of our soul. It is necessary to realize the nature of this plane in order to be relieved of our harmful errors in regard to sexual relationship. Some sort of conviction must precede the actual adoption of any proposed method.

Мой перевод:

> Истина состоит в том, что существует реальная плоскость *для здоровой практики влюбчивости*, являющейся неоъемлемой частью нашей души. Необходимо понять природу этой плоскости, с тем, чтобы освободиться от наших пагубных ошибок в отношении сексуальных отношений. Необходимо наличие определенной убежденности, предшествующей фактическому принятию любого из предложенных методов.

Предлагаемый интернетом перевод "аmorous disposition" как "влюбчивый" не подходит. Мой перевод "влюбчивость" тоже. Для "wholesome" тоже не удается подобрать верное слово.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Правда в том, что есть реальная грань *для благотворного опыта любовной предрасположенности*, каковая является и частицей, и частью нашей души. Необходимо осознать природу этой грани, дабы избегать в дальнейшем наших пагубных ошибок, касающихся отношений между полами. Некое предубеждение тут должно предшествовать фактическому принятию любого из предложенных методов.

Comment: спасибо Matt! Любовная предрасположенность то, что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сказала «Правда в том,что существует *грань* для *здравого использования склонности к любви*...» и т.д.

Comment: На самом деле текст скорее религиозный, чем философский, в нём всё простыми словами излагается, поэтому «матрица» там ни к чему. Вот отсюда этот текст: http://prabhupad.info/?page_id=1230&lang=ru

Comment: А, ну тогда грань.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю индуизм, то там «real plane» означает что-то вроде «план, уровень, аспект реальности».